# How to set size of fieldset box and how to write radiobutton events in HTML or HTML5?

Tags: html, html-parsing

Hi this is my HTML code::::

```
<form>
      <fieldset >
       <legend><b>TRIP</b></legend>
       <p>
            <input type = "radio"
                 name = "radSize"
                 id = "sizeSmall"
                 value = "Pligrimage"
                 />Pilgrimage</br>


          <input type = "radio"
                 name = "radSize"
                 id = "sizeMed"
                 value = "Vaccation" />Vaccation</br>


        </p>       
      </fieldset>     
    </form>
```

i have two problem's (1.) while using `<fieldset>` i want that the box should be just confined to text length it should not expand to whole line.(2.) is it possible to write an `Onclick event for radiobutton`,if so can you please tell me how to write it so that first radio button calls `pilg.html` and the second call `vacc.html` on their click event.

Comment: If you have two separate questions, then please ask two separate questions and not one question with two paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is solved by giving the fieldset a fixed width. If you want this to be dynamic it can be done in css or javascript, but I think a fixed width should suffice in your case.

Your second question can be solved using javascript, but I am not sure why you need these to be radio inputs. Links would be much better here.

Please see the following fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/mrfunnel/EUgLt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Answer for you second question
There are two ways

1. write a javascript method to load the new page 
   call the javascript method by specifying the event onclick="MethodName()"` for the radio button.
   Use the Window .location method to change the current page inside the javascript like :
   window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com")
2. Write the Radio button inside anchor tag give the page url as the href